# Finding the conditional mean and conditional variance

Tags: probability-distributions

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac12 & \text{if |x|+|y| < 1} \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$

Find the conditional mean and the conditional variance of Y given X=x.

So far, I did:

$$\begin{align}
f_X(x) & = \int_{|x|-1}^{1-|x|} \frac12 dy \\
& = \frac12(1-|x|-|x|-1) \\
& = 1-|x| \\
\end{align}$$
$$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac1{2(1-|x|)} \\
E(Y|X=x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y(\frac1{2(1-|x|)}) dy$$

Are my bounds for calculating the marginal density of X correct? Also, what are the bounds for y when calculating the conditional mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is stopping you, here as in other questions you asked on the site, is your way of dealing with indicator functions. Let me suggest to **systematically include indicator functions in the densities**. A first advantage is to reach correct formulas, a second is to make easier the computations you face. In the case at hand,
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{\mathbf 1_{|x|+|y|\lt1}}2,\qquad f_X(x)=f_Y(x)=(1-|x|)\,\mathbf 1_{|x|\lt1},
$$
hence, for every $|x|\lt1$,
$$
f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{\mathbf 1_{|y|\lt1-|x|}}{2(1-|x|)},
$$
and, for $|x|\geqslant1$, $f_{Y\mid X}(\cdot\mid x)$ is undefined.

Now, for every $|x|\lt1$, the function $f_{Y\mid X}(\cdot\mid x)$ is even hence
$$
\mathbb E(Y\mid X=x)=\int_\mathbb Ryf_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\,\mathrm dy=0.
$$
Likewise, for every $|x|\lt1$, the conditional variance is
$$
\mathbb E(Y^2\mid X=x)=\int_\mathbb R y^2f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\,\mathrm dy=\int_{-(1-|x|)}^{1-|x|}y^2\frac{\mathrm dy}{2(1-|x|)}=\frac13(1-|x|)^2.
$$
**Note:** A shortcut, which is specific to the present setting, is to note that the random vector $(X,Y)$ is distributed as $(X,(1-|X|)\cdot U)$ where $U$ is independent on $X$ and uniform on $[-1,1]$. Hence, one the event $[|X|\lt1]$,
$$
\mathbb E(Y\mid X)=(1-|X|)\cdot \mathbb E(U),\qquad\mathbb E(Y\mid X)=(1-|X|)^2\cdot \mathbb E(U^2),
$$
and the formulas above reflect the fact that $\mathbb E(U)=0$ and $\mathbb E(U^2)=\frac13$.